# 401 unauthorized response when doing user registration in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am making a shopify inspired django project using restframework. in my project, I have two types of users, one is the default User model and another is custom user model 'Seller'. Here is the code for the model

```
class SellerUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,email,password=None,**extra_fields):  
        email=self.normalize_email(email)
        user=self.model(email=email,**extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff',True)  #is_staff will let the user made here to have some admin accesses
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,email,password=None,**extra_fields):  # this is a bit unnecessary as seller wont be allowed to acess the administration
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser',True)
        return self.create_user(email,password,**extra_fields)


# Since sellers would be different types of users they are custom users inherited from abstractbaseuser
class Seller(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    email=models.EmailField(unique=True,max_length=255,)   # i don't have to create a passeord field as it is automatically inherited from abstractuser
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    company_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    seller_desc=models.TextField()
    seller_image=models.FileField(upload_to='seller/sellerImage',null=True)
    seller_verification=models.FileField(upload_to='seller/sellerVerification',null=True)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    status=models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True)  #verification status


    objects=SellerUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD='email'   #this makes it so that email is used as a unique identifier and not username
    EMAIL_FIELD='email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=[]

   # some errors that was solved by chat gpt that said to do these.
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('auth.Group', related_name='seller_users')
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField('auth.Permission', related_name='seller_users')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Here is my serializers.py code:

```
class SellerRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Seller
        fields=['email','password','first_name','last_name','company_name','seller_desc','seller_image','seller_verification']
        extra_kwargs={
            'password':{'write_only':True}
        }
    #def create should be done since this is a custom User model
    def create(self,validate_data):
        return Seller.objects.create_user(**validate_data)
```

and In my views.py I have this code:

```
# to generate tokens for seller, we have to do it manually since again, Seller is a custom user model.

from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
def get_tokens_for_user(user):
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

    return {
        'refresh': str(refresh),
        'access': str(refresh.access_token),
    }


class SellerRegistrationView(APIView):  #
    def post(self,request,format=None):
        serializer=SellerRegistrationSerializer(data=request.data) 
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            seller=serializer.save()
            token=get_tokens_for_user(seller)

            seller_data={
                    'id':seller.id,
                    'email':seller.email,
                    'first_name':seller.first_name,
                    'last_name':seller.last_name,
                    'company_name':seller.company_name,
                    'seller_desc':seller.seller_desc,
                    'status':seller.status,
                    'role':'seller'
                }
                
            response_data={
                    'token':str(token),
                    'user':seller_data
                }
            return JsonResponse(response_data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

now with this url:`path('sregister/',SellerRegistrationView.as_view(),name='sregister'),`

when i make the request using thunder client i get this as a response:

`{ "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." }`   with a 401 status . I don't know why this is happenning. i have tried using       `permission_classes=[AllowAny]` in my views but same response.

[image: my api view here, no post option nothing.]

It was working before so i have no idea what i should be doing. only thing  i could turn was chatgpt and it wasn't very helpful.